# document change event not firing in anything but Chromium

Tags: jquery

I load this JS as a separate file, so it is then available after page has completely loaded :

```
    //now load the values from the retrieved table, after a change initiated by user
    $(document).change(function() {

            //all formulae go below here:
        // Ordered trays formula
        $('table.gt-table tbody tr').each(function() {
            var tray = 0;
            var ordcell = 0;

        var traycode= $(this).find("td.gt-col-mygrid1-trays_code div").html();  
         var ordcells= $(this).find("td.gt-col-mygrid1-ordered_cells div").html();  
         if (parseInt(traycode) >0) { 
             tray = parseInt(traycode); 
             } else { 
             tray = 0;
         }
           if (parseInt(ordcells) >0) { 
             ordcell = parseInt(ordcells); 
             } else { 
             ordcell = 0;
         }
         if (tray > 0 && ordcell > 0)  var ordtrays = ordcell/tray;
        if (ordtrays > 0){
            $(this).find("td.gt-col-mygrid1-ordered_trays div").html(ordtrays);
        }
        });
        // end Ordered trays formula
        alert("boo");

    }); // end the window change function
```

But it only works happily in Chromium. Both Opera and Firefox never fire 'boo' when the document is edited (it's a Sigma grid that has editable cells).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the include tag used to include this external `JS` resource?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="formula.js"></script> is the include tag...it gets included just fine, and is visible in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `change` event on `document` is a new thing as of the HTML5 specification (I can't find it in [DOM2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/) [which defines `change` for `input`, `textarea`, and `select`], [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), or [DOM3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)), and although it's *mentioned* by the HTML5 spec, it's not *specified* at all as far as I can see. So I suspect it's not widely-supported (yet?).

Comment: Hmmm, good call. Chromium 18 is what I am working on; obviously it is including this ability ahead of the others. So I guess the answer is to try and address the table itself for changes.